# SharePoint 2010 Blog - My Posts View with Summary type formatting

Tags: blog

I am trying to create a view with just My Posts and have it look just like the summary view (the same defailt formatting as it is on the blog's home page). Whenever I create a view for just My Posts, it works fine but then when I change the setting to Summary, it changes the formatting look but includes ALL of the posts.

I want the look of Summary with just My Posts. Please help!

Thanks